# :hover on mobile (responive web design)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm deveolping a responsive website but i'm finding some issues.

I have a Div with an image and some infos. When the user hover this div, it changes the background and 3 buttons appears.

But the problem is: If i'm using a mobile and click on the div on the position of the button (even before it appears), it is calling the "OnClick" function for the button.

I want to use some function to turn these buttons only clickable after they appears.

This is my JQuery function that control the hover (I've used "this" becaus the div is repeated in a List)

```
        $(this).find(".imovel", this).hover(function(){ 
                $("a.contatos", this).toggle();
                $("a.vermais", this).toggle();
                $(".local", this).toggle();
                $(".valor", this).toggle();                        
        });
```

So, i will really appreciate any help.

[Here is the div before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWqJq.png)
[Here the div after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Roti.png)

If i first click on the position of the phone, it call it's on click function before the hover and the buttons appears, the same occurs to the others buttons.

Thank you!

As you asked, some parts of my code (I didn't created this file, my job was to implement some changes, but one of them need to deal with this click on mobile)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe: true, width: "80%", height: "80%"});


        $('.slider_principal').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true
        });
        $('.ham_menu').click(function () {
            $("#menugeral").toggle();
        });
        // --------
        $(".abrir_ligamos").click(function (e) {
            $(".overlaygeral").show();
            $(".modal_ligamos").show();
        });

        $(this).find(".imovel", this).hover(function(){ 
                $("a.contatos", this).toggle();
                $("a.vermais", this).toggle();
                $(".local", this).toggle();
                $(".valor", this).toggle();                        
        });

        $(".propostabt").click(function () {
                $(".overlaygeral").show();
                $(".modal_proposta").show();
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        });

        $(".overlaygeral").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(".modal_ligamos").hide();
            $(".modal_proposta").hide();
        });

        $(".fechar").click(function () {
            $(".overlaygeral").hide();
            $(".modal_ligamos").hide();
            $(".modal_proposta").hide();
        });
        var sliders = {
            1: {slider: '#slider_imovel', nav: '#slider_imovel_nav'},

        };

        $.each(sliders, function () {

            $(this.slider).slick({
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: false,
                fade: true,
                dots: false,
                asNavFor: this.nav
            });
            $(this.nav).slick({
                slidesToShow: 5,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                asNavFor: this.slider,
                prevArrow: $('.prev'),
                nextArrow: $('.next'),
                centerMode: false,
                focusOnSelect: true,
                dots: false,
                infinite: true
            });

        });
    });
</script>

 <li class="item">
        <section class="imovel" onclick="">
            <figure>
                <div class="imagemProduto" style="background:url('<?= PATH ?>imagens/large/<?= $des_1->arquivo ?>');"></div>
                <section class="imask"></section>

                <section class="selos">
                    <?php
                    if ($des_1->situacao == "e")
                        echo '<p class="mudar">pronto para mudar</p>';
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    if ($des_1->lancamento == "s")
                        echo '<p class="f360">Lançamento</p>';
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    if ($des_1->url_videos != NULL)
                        echo '<p class="video">Vídeo</p>';
                    ?>

                </section>

                <?php
                $banana = true;
                foreach ($favoritos as $favorito) {
                    if ($favorito == $des_1->id) {
                        ?>
                        <a ><button id="<?=$des_1->id?>" name="1" class="ifavoriteRED"></button></a>
                        <?php
                        $banana = false;
                    }
                }
                if ($banana) {
                    ?>
                    <a ><button id="<?=$des_1->id?>" name="2" class="ifavorite"></button></a>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>




                <section class="informa">

                    <p class="local">

                        <span><?= $arr_cidade[$des_1->cidade] ?></span>
                        <span><?= $bairro[$des_1->bairro] ?></span>
                    </p>    

                    <p class="valor">                           
                        <span>a partir de </span>
                        <strong><?= number_format( $des_1->valor , 2, ',', '.'); ?></strong>                        
                    </p>

                    <a class="contatos abrir_ligamos" id="ligamos">
                        <img src="public/images/ligamos.png">
                        <p>ligamos para você</p>
                    </a>

                    <a class="contatos" id="maximizeChat" title="Maximizar" onClick="Tawk_API.maximize();">
                        <img src="public/images/central.png">
                        <p>plantão de vendas</p>
                    </a>

                    <?php
                    $string = utf8_encode($des_1->titulo);
                    $tring = strtolower(strip_tags(preg_replace(array('/[`^~\'"]/', '/([\s]{1,})/', '/[-]{2,}/'), array(null, '-', '-'), iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string))));
                    ?>

                    <a class="vermais" href="<?= PATH ?>imovel/<?= $des_1->id ?>/<?= $tring ?>">VER MAIS DETALHES</a>
                </section>

            </figure>

            <h1><?= ($des_1->titulo) ?></h1>

            <h2><?= $categoria[($des_1->categoria)] ?>  / <?= ($des_1->quarto) ?> Quarto(s) / <?= ($des_1->wc) ?> wcs / <?= ($des_1->garagem) ?> vaga(s) / <?= ($des_1->areautil) ?> m² / Cod:<?= ($des_1->id) ?> </h2>

        </section>
    </li>
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle with your working code?

Comment: I've added some parts of the javascript and Html to my post, can you have a look, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, having some sample HTML or JavaScript code will be much more helpful.
For now I can only guess what the problem might be.

My best guess is that the problem is related to how mouse actions are treated in mobile browsers.

Since there is no mouse in mobile phones, but browsers pretend it has one.
When user taps, mobile browser move the simulated mouse pointer to the position you had tapped.

On mobile browsers, this mouse move movement is instantaneous.

It triggers event in the following order:

- `hover` event - cause your buttons to unhide; this make your buttons clickable
- `click` event - Since buttons is now clickable; and fires the button click handler.

All of these are done in sequence and at the same time, thus causing the issue you are observing.

Here is a jsFiddle you can test this behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/pw7u039h/

**Note**: desktop browser's responsive mode may implements this behaviour differently.

I had replicated this issue with Windows Phone 8, Internet Explorer using the jsFiddle provided above.

Chrome's responsive design mode cannot recreate this issue. Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

**Update**

I have a temporary solution in this jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f1b5e2by/5/

The idea:

When user "hover" over an element in mobile device, JavaScript sets a variable that tells the click handler to ignore the following click.
And clears the ignorance after set amount of time (0.2 second in my example)

This will effectively prevents click handler executes to completion after hover unhides those element and triggered a click event.

**Cons**

- Hard to maintain (e.g. Adding more elements that unhide themselves after hover event)
- Depends on user devices performance. (e.g., JavaScript may executes slowly and does not clear the click ignorance after set amount of time; on a slow mobile phone).

I suggest you use a toggle button to hide and unhide the elements.

And here is a good [article](http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/) to read on dealing with `:hover` event on touch screen devices

**Update**

I updated my first jsFiddle and attempted to solve the problem.
However I find the behavior of my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/pw7u039h/6/
Differs between mobile browsers and responsive design mode.

Hence, I suggest to use toggle button.
Which has same control as if you are using "onHover" to display information to mobile users.

Comment: i've made some edits and added the part of the code to the post, can you please have a look?

Comment: I have created a fiddle using the code provided by you. However, your code contains PHP, so I have to do some makeshift changes to get it run without errors in jsFiddle. Here is the link that demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/f1b5e2by/2/

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
JQuery.click();
```

instead of `onclick`